Использование глагола «повстречать»
Можно ли слово "повстречать" использовать по отношению к неодушевлённым предметам, например "повстречать в лесу ель"?

В словарях (энциклопедическом, многих выражений, Ожегова...) имеется такое значение и управление:
повстречать — кого-что, разг. = встретить; встретить случайно, неожиданно.
✦ Так что теоретически сказать повстречать ель можно.
Ну где же, как не в лесу? Возможно, контекст какой-то особенный, иносказательный?
Обычно, правда, глагол "повстречать" используется с неодушевленными существительными (словами или сочетаниями), если так можно выразиться, приближенными к одушевленности.
Примеры из Нацкорпуса
Томас переоделся в пастушеское одеяние; вскоре он повстречал свадебное шествие и присоединился к нему (Александр Архангельский. Александр I).
Близ Фив на перекрестке он повстречал повозку со стариком и слугами (Анна Чайковская. Миф об Эдипе).
Когда-то Грум-Гржимайло рассказывал отцу, как однажды в Северо-Западном Китае он повстречал целый обоз русских крестьян, которые ходили искать Беловодье (А. А. Уткин. Крепость сомнения).
Вспомнил Иван, как лет тридцать назад повстречали они одну семью алнов (Вадим Бурлак. Хранители древних тайн).
А вот здесь ("Биндюжник и король") — переносный смысл:
Летела пуля,
Чье-то сердце повстречала,
Спросила пуля:
"Отчего ты так стучишь?"
